# Use of the Ambient Light Sensor in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, light-sensor

In my app, which I am implementing it in Xamarin.iOS, I want to measure the ambient light (in lux) from the corresponding sensor or from the front camera.
I cannot find any sample code for this purpose in c# and the documentation of Xamarin does not provide such code.

Comment: There are private APIs in `IOKit` that can access the light sensor but they are not allowed to be used in Store apps. If the user has auto brightness turned on, you can read the current screen brightness via `UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness` but that is not luminance based. You can use `EXIF` metadata and sample the camera output (`DidOutputSampleBuffer`) and grab the `EXIF` metadata from the frame and using the APEX calculation, you can obtain the luminance of the video frame (there are examples of this in the Apple Developer forum, that is where I learn how to do it and convert it to C#).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, there is not a way to directly access the sensor, get readings from it and be able to upload your app then? I think that the "trick" with the camera will do the job. ;)

Comment: All the light meter apps, and others that need a luminance, that I have seen that do not require an external light sensor are doing some type of hack with sampling the camera output, using the EXIF data and/or combining other information from the video frame.